# Graph od periodic extension of function and its Fourier cosine series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

The function $f$ is defined as follows:

$ f(x)= 
   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & ,x \in ( \frac{3}{2}, 2)  \\
      3-x & ,x \in [2,3)
\end{array} 
\right. 
$

I have to find the  Fourier cosine series of this function.

1. Could someone just write or sketch the periodic extension of $f$ on whole real line? What does the even periodic extension look like and what happens on $[0, \frac{3}{2} ]$?
2. When we get the even periodic extension, how are coefficients $a_0, a_n, b_n $ calculated? I suppose that the period is $3 $ but what are the limits of integrals?

I know how to sketch the extension and find coefficients when the function is given on interval of the form $[0,l]$, but here it is not the case, it starts at $\frac{3}{2}$.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the length of the interval where your function is defined? The domain is $(\frac 32,3)$. The length of this interval is $\frac 32$. So you can just shift everything by that value, and your interval will become $(0,\frac 32)$. Then the problem reduces to something that you already know how to solve:
$$ f(x)= 
   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & ,x \in ( 0, \frac{1}{2})  \\
      3-x & ,x \in [\frac 12,\frac32)
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$
While this function is periodic, it is not even. You can extend it as:
$$ f(x)= 
   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x & ,x \in ( 0, 1)  \\
      1 &, x\in [1,2)\\
      3-x & ,x \in [2,3)
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$
Now you can make an even, periodic function out of it.

Comment: Ok, so I simply translate. What about even extension, is that: f(x)= -1 on (-1/2, 0) and f(x)= x - 3 on (-3/2,-1/2)? But in that case,  the function given on [-3/2, 3/2]  is not periodic on real line. I am confused about that.

Comment: If you want to make the function even, you would need to have the period $3$. Let me add the new definition to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!